# Import SQL dump with subprocess

Tags: python, mysql, subprocess

I'm trying to import a .sql dump from disk into MySQL via Python and subprocess. I.e. the equivalent to

```
mysql -u user -ppassword db < dump.sql
```

My Python code looks like this (but I have tried a ton of alternatives :)):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ("mysql -u %s -p%s database"  % (MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD)).split(),
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=False)
out, err = proc.communicate('source /tmp/dump.sql')
```

The application finishes successfully, but there are no rows imported to MySQL. I have also tried pipe the `dump.sql` like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ("mysql -u %s -p%s database < /tmp/dump.sql"  % (MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD)).split(),
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=False)
out, err = proc.communicate()
```

If important, when I set `shell=True` I get `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`)

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: you are supplying the -ppassword , it should be -p password. after fixing this, try with setting shell =True

Comment: I tried, but it only says `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. Which is kind of true, because the proper syntax on command line is `-ppassword` as `-p password` would indicate the database called `password`, right?

Comment: My first comment applies to when I have `.split()` on my command. If I don't, then I get the `mysql` help text instead (like `mysql --help`).

Comment: For anyone coming from *Google*, I had the same problem, but I was using `-p"{}"` (i.e. what you use for `os.system`) instead of  `-p{}` (what you should use for `subprocess.Popen`!!).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using Popen.communicate() wrong.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["mysql", "--user=%s" % USER, "--password=%s" % PASS, "database"],
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate(file("/tmp/dump.sql").read())
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, however the result is the same. This is the new code

    `proc = subprocess.Popen(
        ("mysql -u %s -p%s database" % (MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD)).split(),
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = proc.communicate(file('/tmp/sebbe').read())
    print "out: %s" % out
    print "err: %s" % err`

The output is

    out: None
    err: None

If I skip the `split()` like in your example I this error `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: If fixed the mysql arguments and did a small test run - now it works. My mysql version is 5.5.27.

Comment: @SebastianDahlgren Hi, did the code provided in this answer work? I got an error like this "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory". I am not using "split", how was the error gone finally?

Comment: @nan, I assume so (but it was 2 years ago, so I don't remember in detail). I would guess that the path to your `.sql` file is wrong or that your `mysql` binary isn't in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 18):

If you come to this page from Google, please note, that sigi's answer will work, but it will load all dump file into memory and if it's too big to fit, it will fail.

Here's how I do it:

```
with open(dump_filename, 'r') as f: 
       command = ['mysql', '-u%s' % db_settings['USER'], '-p%s' % db_settings['PASSWORD'], db_settings['NAME']]
       proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin = f)
       stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```

It do the same, but memory consumption is minimal, because the dump is streamed right to the stdin of mysql.